# Serving multiple users at once with a Python Slack bot

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, celery, slack-api

I have a bot written in Python running on Amazon EC2 with Django as a framework. The bot's end goal is to sustain conversations with multiple users on the same Slack team at once. As I understand it, Amazon will handle load-bearing between Slack teams, but I'm trying to figure out how to manage the load within a single Slack.

Right now, my bot sits in a busy loop waiting for a single user to respond. I've been doing some research on this - is Celery the right tool for the job? Should I split each conversation into a separate thread/task, or maybe have a dispatcher handle new messages? Is there a way for Slack to send an interrupt, or am I stuck with while loops?

Thanks for any help/guidance! I'm pretty new to this.

Edit: I managed to solve this problem by implementing a list of "Conversation" objects pertaining to each user. These objects save the state of each conversation, so that the bot can pick up where it left off when the user messages again.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use an async framework for this task. Check out [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You're using the outgoing webhooks from slack, not the Real Time Messaging API
- You're not trying to do some kind of multiple question-answer response where state between each question & answer needs to be maintained.

Skip all the Django stuff and just use AWS Lambda to respond to user requests. That only works for fairly simple "MyBot: do_something_for_me" style things but it's working pretty well for us. Lot easier to manage as well since there's no ec2, no rds, easy deployment, etc. Just make sure you set a reasonable time limit for each Lambda request. From my experience 3 seconds is generally enough time unless you've got a bit of a larger script.

If you really really really have to maintain all this state then you might be better off just writing some kind of quick thing in Flask rather than going through all the setup of django. You'll then have to deal with all the deployment, autoscaling, backup rigmarole that you would for any web service but if you need it, well then ya need it =)

Comment: Just as a quick followup to this, from your question it kinda sounds like you are using the RTM API. Is it possible to redesign what you've done to just use the webhook? If so that's a lot easier to deal with. If not, then as @xyres said you'll need an async framework. Maybe dig into https://github.com/slackhq/python-rtmbot a bit.

Comment: Hmm... So my bot has a brief interaction with the user via Real Time Messaging, then it becomes a relay between two Slacks, shooting messages back and forth via Webhook. Do you think it's possible to use AWS Lambda in conjunction with what I already have set up? Django is up and running, it's just that when two users (test users right now) communicate with the bot at once the wires get crossed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might be able to use the slash commands api to send all that out via a webhook. In your test env you're serving this with gunicorn right? If you're just trying to proxy two different slack teams together are there existing integrations out there for you (e.g. https://sameroom.io/)? If you need a relay like this with state Lambda in this case probably isn't a good fit to much time spend setting up DB connections and teardown.

Comment: Still working through this (may have found a functional workaround), but sure. Thanks for the help